# Google Sheets: Tracking date changes by stage with automated timestamp recording

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm trying to track the date at which a particular stage is selected from a dropdown list, so that I can measure the time between stages. Here is the spreadsheet: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1GEJKCtLgsIobA0u3_GYqYwA6FQuSi64u4ORgTATn92U/edit?usp=sharing

I've been working with different examples to record the timestamp when a cell is changed, but I can't seem to find a way to record a timestamp in **different** cells dependent upon the value selected in the dropdown.

Does anyone know if something like this is possible? A function like this will get me the timestamp in a single column/cell, but I want to be able to populate the different timestamps corresponding to the value in the dropdown  in different cells:

```
function onEdit() {
 var s = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
 if( s.getName() == "Tracking" ) { //checks that we're on the correct sheet
   var r = s.getActiveCell();
   if( r.getColumn() == 2 ) { //checks the column
     var nextCell = r.offset(0, 1);
     if( nextCell.getValue() === '' ) //is empty?
       var time = new Date();
       time = Utilities.formatDate(time, "GMT", "HH:mm:ss");
       nextCell.setValue(time);
   };
 };
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solution:**

You would need to have some parsing of the cell value to separate the number component, compute the offset cell, and write the timestamp there.

Note that my modified code also uses the event object `e`, as this lessens the calls to `SpreadsheetApp` and makes each execution a little bit faster.

**Sample Code:**

```
function onEdit(e) {
  var r = e.range;
  var off = 0;
  if (r.getSheet().getName() == "Tracking") { //checks that we're on the correct sheet
    if (r.getColumn() == 2) { //checks the column
      var arr = e.value.split(" "); // parse the cell value
      if (arr[0] == "Start") {
        off = 1;
      }
      else if (arr[0] == "Stage") {
        off = parseInt(arr[1]) + 1; // compute offset
      }
      else return;

      var nextCell = r.offset(0, off);
      if (nextCell.getValue() === '') { //is empty?
        var time = new Date();
        time = Utilities.formatDate(time, "GMT", "HH:mm:ss");
        nextCell.setValue(time);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Sample Output:**

[image]

**References:**

[Event Objects | onEdit(e)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events#edit)